# Jumbo frames (mtu 9000) on Debian 7.10 servers with BCM57800 NIC (bnx2x)

Tags: linux, debian, mtu, broadcom, jumboframes

I'm working on 2 servers under Debian 7.10 with Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57800 1/10 Gigabit ethernet.

I have done the following for both servers:

`ethtool -g eth0
   Ring parameters for eth0:
   Pre-set maximums:
   RX:      4078
   RX Mini: 0
   RX Jumbo:    0
   TX:      4078
   Current hardware settings:
   RX:      4078
   RX Mini: 0
   RX Jumbo:    0
   TX:      4078`

I changed mtu to 9000 with:
`ifconfig eth0 mtu 9000`

`ifconfig eth0`
value has changed:

`UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1`

But it doesn't work when I try to send 9000 bytes packet with:
`ping -M do -s 8972 10.0.0.3
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3) 8972(9000) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.0.3 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 12095ms`

However it is still working with 1500 bytes packets:

`ping -M do -s 1472 10.0.0.3
PING 10.0.0.3 (10.0.0.3) 1472(1500) bytes of data.
1480 bytes from 10.0.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.054 ms
1480 bytes from 10.0.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms`

NIC firmware:

`/sbin/modinfo bnx2x
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/broadcom/bnx2x/bnx2x.ko
firmware:       bnx2x/bnx2x-e2-7.8.19.0.fw
firmware:       bnx2x/bnx2x-e1h-7.8.19.0.fw
firmware:       bnx2x/bnx2x-e1-7.8.19.0.fw
version:        1.78.19-0
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM57710/57711/57711E/57712/57712_MF/57800/57800_MF/57810/57810_MF/57840/57840_MF Drive`

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the switch isn't letting the packets through.  Some pcaps might also be diagnostically useful.

Comment: You're right, thank you. Jumbo frames weren't activated in the switch configuration.